# Populating a Dictionary with PdfOutlines

Tags: c#, arrays, pdfsharp

So I am attempting to write a program that combines a PDF from a list of PDF's that are already available.  I've got most of it done to this point, but I'm having an issue with one step in particular. I'm also writing this in c# if that isn't apparent.

I have an array of strings that contains a category name, and for each category name I want to create a variable of type PdfOutline that gets initialized to null that I can iterate through later in the program.

I've tried to look into this myself and it seems like dictionary is the way to do it, but I'm not really sure how to go about it.  Firstly, is making a dictionary the right way to do it and secondly I need help with implementation.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following would work (not syntax-checked this, sorry):

```
// This requires the array of Categories to have no duplicates.
public Dictionary<string, PdfOutline> BuildUpMyCollectionOfOutlines(string[] categories)
{
    return categories.ToDictionary(cat => new KeyValuePair<string, PdfOutline>(cat, null));
}
```

If you do it this way, then you can later consume the result as such (although having a function to do this is silly, is just my way to show you how to consume it):

```
public PdfOutline GetOutlineByCategory(Dictionary<string, PdfOutline> outlines, string category)
{
    // This will be problematic if the category isn't actually in the dictionary.
    return outlines[category];
}
```

Whether you should use a `Dictionary<string, PdfOutline>` versus something else, like a `List<KeyValuePair<string, PdfOutline>>` depends on 1) how many of these you'll have and 2) how you'll be accessing them. For example, if you have 10,000 of them and you need to randomly and repeatedly find them by Category name, then the Dictionary is the right approach because it hashes things for quicker searching (think an index in a table in a database). However, if you have 10,000 but only need to find 2 of them, or vice versa, only have 10 of them, then the overheads in building up that quick-searching capability is wasted. So Dictionary vs other is best answered by the question, "If this was in a database table, would you index it?"